# How to define QML component inline and override a property?

Tags: qml, qqmlcomponent

I'm trying and failing at something seemingly simple: define a simple text formatting component inline, then instantiate it multiple times with different text. Here's the code

```
Item {
.
.
.
Component {
    id: favButtonLabelText
    Text {
        text: "Blah!"
        color: StyleSingleton.xNavPrimaryText
        font.family: StyleSingleton.xNavTextFont
        font.pointSize: 28
    }
}
.
.
.       
Loader { sourceComponent: favButtonLabelText; text: "Diameter" }
```

At the Loader line, the text property is invalid. Attempts to define a property or alias on the component are rejected with "Component objects cannot declare new properties".

The only example I find in the docs, shows overriding the `x` property of a `Rectangle` defined in an inline component. It seem to me overriding the `text` property of a `Text` element is analogous.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `Loader` sets itself as the context object for the component it is loading, you could define a property in it and use it in the loaded `Item`.
However, you have to use a property name not used by your item, otherwise it will be shadowed by your item's own property and there's no easy way to access a context property explicitly.

```
Component {
    id: favButtonLabelText
    Text {
        text: foobar
    }
}
Loader {
    sourceComponent: favButtonLabelText
    property string foobar: "Diameter"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As of Qt 5.15, a new feature has been added: [inline Components](https://www.qt.io/blog/new-qml-language-features-in-qt-5.15)

As the name suggests, it allows to define an component inline, with the benefits of:

> You can create an instance of the component, without the overhead of using a Loader.
> You can use the component type in property declarations.
> You can refer to the component in other files than the one it is defined in.

```
Item {
.
.
.
component FavButtonLabelText: Text {
     property int aCustomProp: 0

     text: "Blah!"
     color: StyleSingleton.xNavPrimaryText
     font.family: StyleSingleton.xNavTextFont
     font.pointSize: 28
}
.
.
.      
FavButtonLabelText { text: "myNewText"; aCustomProp: 5 }
```

Comment: The new accepted answer should be this one

Answer (score 6):

As **GrecKo** already said, it is possible to use a custom property of the `Loader` that has another name like in his example `foobar`.

If you don't do any fancy reparenting of the loaded `Item` it is also possible to use the same name, and reference it with `parent.property`

```
Component {
    id: textComponent
    Text {
        // Use "parent" to reference the property of the parent,
        // which is by default the Loader
        text: parent.text
    }
}

Column {
    Repeater {
        model: ['hallo welt', 'hello world', 'Bonjour monde', '你好世界']
        delegate: Loader {
            property string text: modelData
            sourceComponent: textComponent
        }
    }
}
```